# ASP.NET MVC editing parts of model which is not initially given values // db.saveChanges() doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have created a model with a controller and a view in my ASP.NET MVC application. Initially, when a new application is created using the create action, the user doesn't have the possibility to fill in 5 of the parts of the model (see code).
Editing is only possible when logging in as an admin, not as any user. Getting the edit page for the right application connected to the right user is not a problem. HOWEVER, when I fill in the checkboxes and write any comments etc. in the 'edit mode', and press submit, nothing happens. It seems the changes are not registered by the program (db.SaveChanges() doesn't work??)

Please, do someone know how I can fix this, or to begin with, what the problem is? It is almost as if the save button is just a shell, so might there me a connection or something missing?

Thank you for your time.

**code:**

part of the model (last 5 are not filled in in 'create mode'

```
[Display(Name = "Course for master")]
        public string Course_Master { get; set; }
       
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Words for Office")]
        [MaxLength(3000)]
        public string Motivation { get; set; }

        //[DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        [Display(Name = "Upload Resume")]
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose file to upload")]
        public string Resume { get; set; }

//these 5 are the ones I want to edit
        public bool Interview { get; set; } //checkbox
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public bool Unfit { get; set; } //checkbox
        public bool Candidate { get; set; } //checkbox
```

razor page

```
@model NEA.Models.Application
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Edit</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit","Applications", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Application</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Interview, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Interview)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Interview, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Unfit, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Unfit)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Unfit, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Candidate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Candidate)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Candidate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

action

```
// GET: Applications/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Application application = db.Applications.Find(id);
            if (application == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(application);
        }
// POST: Applications/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(Application application)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(application).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(application);
        }
```

**Edit**

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(Application application)
        {
                //db.Entry(application).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.Entry(application).Property(o => o.Interview).IsModified = true;
                db.Entry(application).Property(o => o.Comments).IsModified = true;
                db.Entry(application).Property(o => o.Notes).IsModified = true;
                db.Entry(application).Property(o => o.Unfit).IsModified = true;
                db.Entry(application).Property(o => o.Candidate).IsModified = true;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            //return View(application);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to fix it, whilst keeping `@Html.BeginForm()` empty

edit action

```
// POST: Applications/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(Application application, string id)  
        {
            var data = db.Applications.Find(id);
            data.Interview = application.Interview;
            data.Comments = application.Comments;
            data.Notes = application.Notes;
            data.Unfit = application.Unfit;
            data.Candidate = application.Candidate;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change certain values, according to your above code does not know which property is modified. You can set properties as `isModified=true` that you want to change value of properties.

**EDIT:**

```
            db.Application.Attach(application);
            db.Entry(application).Property(o => o.Interview).IsModified = true;
            db.Entry(application).Property(o => o.Comments).IsModified = true;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Or you can make this below way with list;

```
var included= new[] { "Interview ", "Comments " };
var entry = context.Entry(obj);
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;

foreach (var name in included)
{
   entry.Property(name).IsModified = true;
}
```

Comment: Does this then also work if not all of the parts are modified each time? So they have the possibility to edit all of the last 5, but will this method work if they only make changes to say one or two of them?

Comment: This way is used to update one or more desired properties.You can add desired properties to included list. Of course there are many ways but it is one of them.  Did you try above solution? If it is, what is the problem?

Comment: Thank you, that was dumb from my part. Ive done as you suggested now and remove the ```if ModelState.IsValid``` statement, as this checks whether the user Id of the current user matches that of the one being edited, which it clearly wont. The error which then occurs is ```Member 'IsModified' cannot be called for property 'Interview' because the entity of type 'Application' does not exist in the context. To add an entity to the context call the Add or Attach method of DbSet<Application>``` (Ill add my new code as an edit in my Q)

Comment: You can try with adding `db.Application.Attach(application);` before setting ismodified properties.

Comment: That does not work because it doesn't add the modified values to the already existing user, rather adds a new record, which is not the goal